# Center str in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

i'm trying to center the text of a string but i can't do it. I checked mutiple posts and tried  what they said, i don't get an error but the text is still aligned to the left. here the code and the str i want to center

```
while True:
        print ''
        while True:
                try:
                    userNum = float(raw_input('Enter the total of your bill: '))

                    if (userNum) > 0 and (userNum) != 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print 'Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...'
```

Comment: your `try:` statement has no `except:` part. Where do you try to center something in this code. A `print` statement without a final `,` will start the next print on a new line, i.e. left aligned.

Comment: it does have one, i just didn't paste it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). The `^80`  format tells Python to make the string 80 characters long, and to center the argument:

```
print('{:^80}'.format('Oops!  That was not a valid number.  Try again...'))
```

yields

```
               Oops!  That was not a valid number.  Try again...
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked but how would i apply this to that string?
userNum = float(raw_input(('{:^80}'.format('Enter the total of your bill:'))))

it seems to put spaces after the string too... but what if i want it just before and not after?

Comment: @AdrianSultu: Use `^` to center the argument, `>` for right justification, `<` for left justification. The documentation of `str.format` is a little daunting at first (it is like an arcane mini-language), but it is so chock-full of goodies it is well worth taking the time to master.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this [str.center](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.center)